# pivoting rows to columns in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have the following table with the following sample data

```
ID  Language       Question       SubQuestion     SubSubQuestion    TotalCount  TotalPercent
3      E               9               0                1             88527            73%
3      E               9               0                2             19684            16%
3      E               9               0                3             12960            11%
3      E               9               0                9              933              1%
```

I want all in one row like this

```
    ID  Language        TotalCount901   TotalPercent901     TotalCount902   TotalPercent902 TotalCount903   TotalPercent903
     3       E            88527           73%                 19684             16%              12960              11%
```

I've tired using the pivot command, but it dosnt to work for me.

Comment: By "doesn't work" you mean it throws an error, gives undesired results, something else?

Comment: Test fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a3fc/1

Comment: What is the grouping criteria?  Is the number of sub / subsub questions dynamic?  It's difficult to pivot with a dynamic number of columns, as you will require the use of dynamically-generated SQL code.  Are you using any sort of application language to display the results that you could do the pivoting in?  That is typically easier for dynamic column width scenarios.

Comment: It works, but I am not getting the results I want. My logic is all wrong. Can post code if need. @mellamokb, I believe the grouping should be by ID and lang. Ie, i want just one row for ID and lang (in my real table, i have many ids and many lang).

Comment: No, the sub/subsub/subsubsub isnt dynamic. There will always be three of them. If you mean the values, then also NO! however they have numeric values in them

Comment: @masfenix: OK, that will make it a lot simpler :).  So do you also always leave out SubSubQuestion = 9?

Comment: What do you mean leave out? Maybe I can rephrase this. For every combination of Q, SubQ, SubSUbQ I want it one row. Does that make sense?

Comment: @masfenix: I mean in your example, you have SubSubQuestion 1, 2, 3, and 9.  But in your output, you only have `Total*901`, `Total*902`, and `Total*903`.  What about `Total*909`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few assumptions based on your column names, but it looks like you want to use something similar to this.  This applies both an `UNPIVOT` and then a `PIVOT` to get the values in the columns you requested:

```
select *
from
(
  select id,
    language,
    col + cast(QUESTION as varchar(10))
      +cast(subquestion as varchar(10))
      +cast(SubSubQuestion as varchar(10)) col,
    value
  from
  (
    select id, language,
      cast(TotalCount as varchar(10)) TotalCount, 
      totalPercent,
      question, subquestion, SubSubQuestion
    from yourtable
  ) usrc
  unpivot
  (
    value 
    for col in (totalcount, totalpercent)
  ) un
) srcpiv
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([TotalCount901], [totalPercent901], 
              [TotalCount902], [totalPercent902], 
              [TotalCount903], [totalPercent903],
              [TotalCount909], [totalPercent909])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a482e/6)

Note: when performing the `UNPIVOT` the columns need to be of the same datatype.  If they are not, then you will need to convert/cast to get the datatypes the same.

If you have an unknown number of values to transform, you can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)


select @colsPivot 
  = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
             + QUOTENAME(c.name +
                        cast(QUESTION as varchar(10))
                        +cast(subquestion as varchar(10))
                        +cast(SubSubQuestion as varchar(10)))
           from yourtable t
           cross apply sys.columns as C
           where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
              C.name in ('TotalCount', 'TotalPercent')
           group by c.name, t.question, t.subquestion, t.subsubquestion
           order by t.SubSubQuestion
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'select *
              from
              (
                select id,
                  language,
                  col + cast(QUESTION as varchar(10))
                    +cast(subquestion as varchar(10))
                    +cast(SubSubQuestion as varchar(10)) col,
                  value
                from
                (
                  select id, language,
                    cast(TotalCount as varchar(10)) TotalCount, 
                    totalPercent,
                    question, subquestion, SubSubQuestion
                  from yourtable
                ) usrc
                unpivot
                (
                  value 
                  for col in (totalcount, totalpercent)
                ) un
              ) srcpiv
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @colsPivot + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/acc19/6)

Comment: +1 Excellent answer.  I would only suggest it seems the OP is leaving out the SubSubQuestion=9 entry.  Also, here is proof that it handles multiple ID and Language scenario as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b91b0/1

Comment: @mellamokb that is what I thought too, but I assumed that it was part of the column name.  Not sure though as the requirements are not 100% clear. And I included all values just for the example.

Comment: I used yours, but got nulls everywhere. I will look at the query again to see if I missed anything

Comment: @masfenix if you include additional fields in the `PIVOT` portion of the query you can get nulls, you have to only include the fields that are needed to perform the transformation

Comment: I havn't added or removed fields, just changes a few names (since my table field names are a bit different (wanted to be safe and not post company data)). I will update and let you know. Thankyou SO much. It looks like the sqlfiddle is exactly what I need..

EDIT: found the mistake. THANKS guys. and wow beautiful answer.

Comment: @masfenix glad you figured it out, I also updated my answer to include a dynamic sql version if you need it.